# Show that $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\ge \left(n+1\right)^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Show that $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\ge \left(n+1\right)^{1/n}$.

I would like a hint for this problem. I have shown that for each term being summed up. Let $a_{1}$ = (1 + $\frac{1}{\:k_{1}}$) and continue until $a_{n}$. The LHS looks exactly like the arithmetic mean. So I attempted to show that $a_{1}*a_{2}*...*a_{n} \ge (n+1)$. But (n+1) is slightly bigger. I do know that a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{n} is bigger than (n+1). But I am unsure on how to proceed.

Comment: Adding `\:` between `\sum` and `_{k=1}^n` is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 3):

That's just the inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean: the LHS is the arithmetic mean, the RHS is $$(n+1)^{1/n}=\sqrt[n]{\prod^n_{k=1}\frac{k+1}k}=\sqrt[n]{\prod^n_{k=1}\left(1+\frac1k\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you, the problem stated for me to show that the inequality holds for all n greater than or equal to 1. Would it be sufficient to state that n+1 can be rewritten as  $$(n+1)^{1/n}=\sqrt[n]{\prod^n_{k=1}\frac{k+1}k}=\sqrt[n]{\prod^n_{k=1}\left(1+\frac1k\right)}$$ How did you know you could rewrite (n+1)^1/n in that manner?

Comment: @dfk3 Erm... $$n+1=\prod^n_{k=1}\frac{k+1}k=\frac21\cdot\frac32\cdot\frac43\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{n+1}n$$ is crucial, here, it's a so-called "telescoping product", where everything cancels out but the first denominator and the last numerator. It's a quite common technique with products and sums.